# Large toque and small speed

Tags: motor

I need a motor that drive a piston with 7854 kg loading and the piston speed is 4.24 mm/min. Where can I find such motor?

Comment: It's called "gears" - look them up.

Comment: 4mm/min and tons of weight is typical for a hydraulics application.

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out torque and RPM to select a motor. If you can not find a motor that has a low enough RPM, you need a speed reduction gear. You can probably find a motor with attached gear (gear-motor) rated for the required output torque and RPM.